# CSS or HTML5 image change onClick

Tags: css, html

I would like simply an effect like is shown with the Sign in / register buttons on this website:

http://css-tricks.com/forums/entry/register

I've tried "Inspect Element" on this page but can't figure out how its being achieved.

i.e. hover over them and they change subtly. Click them and they appear to be "pressed in" for as long as you hold the mouse key down. Release mouse key and they pop back out.

Using a javascript solution at the moment but not very happy with it. Would prefer to leave javascript out. Far too much effort trying to get it to work in Chrome as well as IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you mean the active state. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6hzcf/1/).

```
.button, #rcp_submit {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    outline: 0;
    background: #4e68c7;
    box-shadow: 1px 0px 1px #203891, 0px 1px 1px #3852b1, 2px 1px 1px #203891, 1px 2px 1px #3852b1, 3px 2px 1px #203891, 2px 3px 1px #3852b1, 4px 3px 1px #203891, 3px 4px 1px #3852b1, 5px 4px 1px #203891, 4px 5px 1px #3852b1, 6px 5px 1px #203891;
    color: white;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-family:'Gotham Rounded A', 'Gotham Rounded B', "proxima-nova-soft", sans-serif;
    padding: 9px 16px;
    line-height: 1.4;
    position: relative;
    top: -5px;
}
.button:hover, .button:focus, #rcp_submit:hover, #rcp_submit:focus {
    color: white;
    background: #3d57b4;
}
.button:active, #rcp_submit:active {
    box-shadow: 1px 0px 1px #203891, 0px 1px 1px #3852b1, 2px 1px 1px #203891, 1px 2px 1px #3852b1, 3px 2px 1px #203891;
    -webkit-transform: translate(3px, 3px);
    -moz-transform: translate(3px, 3px);
    -ms-transform: translate(3px, 3px);
    -o-transform: translate(3px, 3px);
    transform: translate(3px, 3px);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That looks useful however not quite sure how to put it to use. I need a grid of 3 x 4 buttons inside a <td> tag, different texts on each button, as each links to a separate page. - how could I use the code to achieve this?

Comment: I was trying, said I had to wait x minutes :)

Comment: Don't suppose you can show how to change the colour of the button face on hover?